# How to way extract format .gz/.zip/.rar/.tar.gz in .net core mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have issue when action open file follow format .gz/.tar.gz
This is image error[image]

This is code:

```
 public void Check(string path)
    {
        foreach (var fileName in Directory.GetFiles(path))
        {
            if (Path.GetExtension(fileName) == ".gz" && Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName).Contains("tar"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(fileName);

                ExtractTGZ(fileName, Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName) + @"\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName));
                System.IO.File.Delete(fileName);

            }
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The System.IO.Compression namespace contains the following types for compressing and decompressing files and streams. You can also use these types to read and modify the contents of a compressed file.

```cs
string fileName = Guid.NewGuid() + ifile.FileName;
string path = Path.Combine(FilesTempPath, fileName);
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
{
    ifile.CopyTo(fileStream);
}

var FileZipPath = FilesTempPath + "\\" + fileName;
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(FileZipPath, FilesTempPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following example from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.gzipstream?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0) shows how to use the GZipStream class to compress and decompress a directory of files.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).